# Java Spring Boot external logging file jar

Tags: java, spring, logging, jar, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application I want to use logging to an external file.

So I configured application.properties like this:

```
# LOGGING
logging.path=/var/logs
logging.file=my-application.log
```

I want to us the application on a windows system and want to use NSSM to start the jar file as a windows service.

Also I want the external logfile I mentioned.

At the current state I tested this configuration only in my eclipse and the logfile called `my-application.log` is only present in my classpath.

There was no folder `var` created.

Anyway...

How can I configure this application logging to work like I wanted.

- Use Spring Boot application as jar
- Wrap it with NSSM to run as a windows service
- Have an external logging file at the Location "D:\applications\SpringBootApp\logging\data.log"

Comment: Not sure about NSSM, but for the logging if you're using maven, you could parametrize the path & file name using [profiles based on the OS family](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireOS.html). Otherwise you could define [spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) with [separate property files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) and activate them from the startup scripts

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting the properties on the launcher command line. Add them to your service wrapper the same way you'd add other command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I think u must mention the drive or the network location u need to put that log file .

for ex: `D:var/logs`